# Как указать границы (x) при подсчёте определённого интеграла по значениям функции (y) при помощи numpy.trapz

Tags: python, numpy

Есть таблично заданная функция

```
y = 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  
x = 10 11 12 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Нужно посчитать определённый интеграл х от 10 до 20 методом трапеций при помощи numpy.trapz

```
y = [i for i in range(11)]
x = [i+10 for i in range(11)]
result = numpy.trapz(y)
```

Оно то выдаёт правильный ответ 50. Но я ведь передаю только массив у. Как указать границы 10-20, и куда вписать массив Х ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если вы задаете точки в качестве значений `y`, то определенный интеграл (площадь трапеций) не изменится от того что вы передвинете все точки влево или вправо, поэтому нет смысла задавать точки по оси `X`. Если вы хотите ограничить точки слева или справа - сделайте это с массивом точек `Y`:

```
In [28]: a = np.arange(11)

In [29]: a
Out[29]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])

In [30]: np.trapz(a)
Out[30]: 50.0

In [31]: a[1:10]
Out[31]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [32]: np.trapz(a[1:10])
Out[32]: 40.0
```

Если же вы хотите интегрировать **функцию** (а не значения) на определенном интервале:

```
In [33]: from scipy import integrate as ig

In [34]: ig.quad(np.sin, a=0, b=np.pi)
Out[34]: (2.0, 2.220446049250313e-14)
```

`a` - нижний предел, `b` - верхний

Answer (score 1):

Границы по `x` можно ограничить, с помощью неравенств:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(10, 21)
>>> y = np.arange(11)
>>> np.trapz(y)
50.0
>>> np.trapz(y[(x >= 11) & (x < 18)])
24.0
```